# Как дополнить строку нужными символами

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос, знаю как дополнить строку нулями

```
System.out.println(String.format("%010d",123));
```

Но как заменить 0 на другой символ?

Comment: `String.format("%10d",123).replace(' ', '*')` - не подойдёт?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В **данном** случае, например, вот так:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%10d", 123).replace(' ', 's'));
```

Как реализовать это средствами стандартного `String.format(...)` в **общем** случае, точно не скажу. Но это можно осуществить с помощью, как минимум:

1. [Apache commons library](https://commons.apache.org/): `StringUtils.leftPad("test", 10, 's');`
2. [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava): `Strings.padStart("test", 10, 's');`.

Так же метод с подобным функционалом можно самому реализовать, ибо элементарно.

Answer (score 0):

String.format("%010d",123)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Как ваш ответ отвечает на вопрос в этой теме?